# Sublime Text 3 - Jump to Javascript class

Tags: sublimetext3

This feels basic but I can't seem to get Sublime Text 3 to jump to the definition of a Javascript class  across files. For example, with 2 files...

*app.js*

```
var myThing = new models.Thing();
```

*thing.js*

```
models.Thing = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

I can't find anyway to jump to the definition of `models.Thing`. **Jump to Definition** doesn't work and **Goto Symbol** will only find the `new models.Thing()` instantiation code itself.

I've tried SublimeCodeIntel and various other packages. Tern seemed to work sometimes but often would hang Sublime.

This works seamlessly in a JetBrains IDE like RubyMine. Is this just not possible in Sublime 3?

thanks